# how to align content horizontally central using col-md

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I write code using bootstrap, I come to this problem. I want to align content to the center of the screen. I always write up code like this:

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            Content here   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Meaning I have 3 columns, and I will write code just in the middle column, therefore content will be in the center of the screen.

And if I want to align text and buttons centrally in the middle column, there is another problem and I always write 3 more columns...

Here is an example of what i mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/20f24vLv/11/

Is there a way of avoiding this... I think it takes up too much time and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn_wrapper{
  background-color:red;
  height:300px; 
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn_wrapper button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 btn_wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button
          </button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add text-center class 
 i.e. `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 text-center"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap offset classes to make the div center horizontally and use flexbox to align the inner content center horizontally and vertically

```css
#mydiv2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <div id="mydiv2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, and posted some minutes before :)

Answer (score 1):

Use offset instead of adding a column before. You don't need the last column either if you close the row after your content:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-12">
        Content here   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin: 0 auto` would be enough in this case.

```css
#mydiv1{
  background-color:#000;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#mydiv2{
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#mydiv3{
  background-color:lime;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div id="mydiv1">     
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div id="mydiv2">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Button
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div id="mydiv3">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

@edit

Also:

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            Content here   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Will not center your content becuase columns must add up to 12. In your case they only add up to 9 it would have to be `col-md-4`

Comment: don't think this is what i'm looking for. i'm trying to avoid writing the other two columns. i added div's in the question just for the case study

Comment: it was a copy paste mistake, the jsfiddle used col-md-4.

Comment: Also, not sure if I'm understing correctly what you are trying to achive but check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/20f24vLv/28/ let me know if that's what you were looking for